# Share Facebook User ID between more than one application

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I have three application, every one use a Facebook application.
I get the Facebook userInfo with Api as follows:

```
[[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:appDelegate.fbSession graphPath:@"me"] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *fbuser,
           NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"userid:%@",fbuser.id);
             }
         }];
```

If I use different Facebook application, fbuser.id is different.
How could I make three application use the same fbuser.id?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are going wrong somewhere. User_id is unique always. it will never differ though you login in different applications.

Comment: @Chetan: Ever heard of app-scoped user_ids introduced with Graph API v2.0?

Comment: @Tobi : Thanks to update me.. i had used graph api a long before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the introduction of Graph API v2.0, user_ids are app-scoped, meaning that the same user will have different user_ids with different apps.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

There's the possibility to map the user_ids via the Business Mapping API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

> The Business Mapping API is only useful for businesses who operate multiple user-facing apps and whom need to map the same app-scoped user IDs across them, for cross-promotion for example.

Comment: Thanks {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10153949089790582", 
      "app": {
        "name": "Business's App 1", 
        "namespace": "business_app_1", 
        "id": "647733625268125"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "id": "605665581", 
      "app": {
        "name": "Business's App 2", 
        "namespace": "business_app_2", 
        "id": "370612223054807"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "id": "10154053730190582", 
      "app": {
        "name": "Business's App 3", 
        "namespace": "business_app_3", 
        "id": "194890427204075"
      }
    }
  ]
}  I can get more appID and userID together?

Comment: I guess you need to call https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/ids_for_business

Comment: This edge returns the list of IDs that this user has in any of those other apps. So I can get every userID for every app. Then do more work.