# Facebook id obtained from android sdk is not same as obtained from graph

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I followed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started `A minimum viable social application` to get facebook id of my account  and i've got `604581512992029`. When i check with https://graph.facebook.com/frakc.stran the id is `100003205573681`. Whichi Id i should use?

Comment: You should use the app id that your app returned

Comment: @WizKid you mean the app id genereted in facebook app dashboard, when I register my app? I am using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you seem to use two different Facebook apps, and therefore receive two different app-scoped user_ids.

Have a look at my answer here: [Share Facebook User ID between more than one application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439147/share-facebook-user-id-between-more-than-one-application/25444468#25444468)

Comment: the 60* is obtained from my app, the 100 just from desctop broweser, which is not mine.